# Projector ceiling mounting using 2 screws instead of 4: risky?

Tags: projector

I want to ceiling mount my projector using [this projector ceiling mount](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UMount-Universal-Projector-Ceiling-Bracket/dp/B00AN5I18U/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top). However I realize my ceiling beams are too thin to receive the 4 screws necessary to attach it.

The only way would be, not to install it so that the square of the mount basis be parallel to the projection screen, but rather diagonally with an angle of 45 degrees (so that one of the 4 square corners directly faces the projection screen). In that scenario the mount would be attached to the ceiling with only 2 screws.

Note that the mount + the projector together weight about 4 kilos. The screws are 1cm in diameter, 5cm deep.

What do you think? Risky? Acceptable?

Comment: Do you have an old house, with small children?  If so, the shaking from the kids jumping on the couch (no matter how many times you've told them not to) could be a problem w/ a less than ideally mounted projector.

Comment: Do you have attic access? I'd get up in the attic and sister a 2x4 flush with the bottom of the ceiling joist. Do both sides if you need 4.5" wide rather than 3" wide. Then no more worries, you can mount it using all 4 screws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 kg is not very heavy.  2 screws should be no problem, for the weight.  1 cm diameter screws are very strong and would hold 10 times that much weight.  Even 4mm to 6mm screws would be plenty enough to hold up 4kg.

Based on the mount that you linked to, you should not need to install it at a 45 degree angle.  The tilt section of the mount (as shown in the linked picture) does not rotate, so you probably want to keep the base square/parallel with the screen.  The side holes will be enough to secure it.

Is this an exposed beam you are attaching to, or is it a finished ceiling (drywall/sheetrock or plasterboard) with the beam (rafter or joist) above it?  If it is a finished ceiling, you also could attach a large board so that it reaches across two beams (such as 15mm to 20mm plywood, perhaps 30cm by 60cm or however far it is between beams), and secure the projector mount to the board.  Four screws in the corners of the board to the two beams, and four screws in the corners of the mount to the board, would be very strong and secure.

Comment: I'd opt for the 2 screws solution. You're right, side holes are the way to go! It's a finished ceiling, do you think I could add screws in the remaining holes that would merely lie in the plasterboard? Could that add extra solidity or is it a waste of time?

Comment: My guess is that it would not make much difference. You can get anchors to hold screws in plaster, but they are a poor substitute for screwing into the beam and won't add much help. The beam will give you all the strength you need.

Comment: To prevent the screws from loosening, use lock washers.

![flat washer and lock washer](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/Rondelle_03.jpg/800px-Rondelle_03.jpg)

Screw head, lock washer, flat washer, mounting bracket, in that order.

Answer (score 2):

For my own experience with a projector mounted from the ceiling and only 2 screws (the mounting kit I've purchased only had two), it holds without problem but:

- **Check the screws often!**

I believe it might be caused by the vibrations of the projector's fan, but I've found both screws getting loose by time. In my case, it's really hard to tighten them, so I have no other option than periodic checking...

Answer (score 1):

I would think the way you mentioned would be fine. 
Just use good size screws.

But would be safer an better if you climb up there and add more support. By screwing in beams where you need them.